# Pie charts in ggplot2 with variable pie sizes

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, pie-chart

I've tried various ways to get a `facet_grid` of pie charts in ggplot2 to vary width/radii according to another variable (strength).

geom_bar accepts width=0.5 as a parameter but it is ignored once `coord_polar` is added.  `Adding width=0.5` to the ggplot `aes` or adding a `aes` to `geom_bar` doesn't work.  I can't see any other relevant options for `coord_polar`.  What's the easiest way to do this? The code below makes a nice grid of pie charts but doesn't change the sizes of the pie charts.  What am I missing?

```
mydata <- data.frame(side1=rep(LETTERS[1:3],3,each=9),
                     side2=rep(LETTERS[1:3],9,each=3),
                     widget=rep(c("X","Y","Z"),9*3),
                     val=runif(9*3),
                     strength=rep(c(1,2,3),3,each=3))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x="",y = val, fill = widget, width = strength)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill") +
  facet_grid(side1 ~ side2) +
  coord_polar("y") +
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_blank())
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=strength/2, y = val, fill = widget, width = strength)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(side1 ~ side2) + 
  coord_polar("y") + 
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it!  Makes sense now, the bars have to be left-aligned in a non polar system.  I am still a bit unclear on why strength/2 is the magic number, but will have to do some more reading on how aes handles x values in geom_bar.