# How to use R to plot a pie plot with different radius?

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

For example,

> pie(1:3)

But the radius is constant.

How to make the pie plot which the radius is 1,2,3 respectively?

Comment: So that every slice has a different radius according to its value? Or like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612920/pie-charts-in-ggplot2-with-variable-pie-sizes

Comment: @Iris No, I mean that different component have differents radius in the same figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [radial.pie](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/radial.pie) function in plotrix package

```
install.packages("plotrix")
library(plotrix)
radial.pie(c(1,2,3), labels=c("One", "Two", "Three"), radlab=TRUE)
```

would produce following figure[image]

Comment: The radius does not fit to the numbers. How could you achieve that "one" has the radius 1, "two" has the radius 2 ....? @lovedynasty

Comment: From the figure above I see radius of green is 2 times radius of red and  that of blue is exactly 3 times that of red. If you want to remove those labels 1, 1.5, 2 you can use show.grid.labels=FALSE option and if you wnat that two rings above red removed, you can use grid.col option to set it to your background.

Comment: @lovedynasty It really make sense. But I have another question: In `radial.pie` how to control the absolute radius? You know, `radial.pie(1:3)` and `radial.pie(c(2,4,6))` will be the same. Could I reduce the size of the former?

Comment: @FengTian : I am not sure if that is a desirable feature, but in any case that feature does not seem to be available in `radial.pie` as of now. As the author says he is willing to listen to feedback and improve, may be it is worth giving him this feedback.