# Scaling multiple pie charts in a grid according to their sample size in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I want to create a grid containing 3 pie charts (my real data is big and here is an example) with each chart being scaled according to its sample size. For example, the plot for row 2, location b, should have the minimum size and row 3, location c should have the maximum size. Here is a similar question: [Scaling multiple pie charts in a grid according to their size in R using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682702/scaling-multiple-pie-charts-in-a-grid-according-to-their-size-in-r-using-ggplot2)

Could you please help me with that?thank you.

here is my df:

```
x <- data.frame(
  location = c("a", "b", "c"),
  samplesize = c(26, 3, 96),
  a1 = c(12, 2, 77),
  a2 = c(24, 1, 31),
  a3 = c(15, 2, 56)
)
```

Comment: Can you explain more about how your question is different, or what happened when you tried to use the answers there? From my outside perspective it looks pretty similar.

Comment: No. my dataframe is different. I have three columns for each location and in that dataframe, all of the cases is in one column. I tried to change the dataframe to that format, but idk why it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just roll my own pie chart function and draw this with `geom_polygon`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

make_pie <- function(x, y, size, groups, n, rownum) {
  angles <- c(0, 2*pi * cumsum(n)/sum(n))
  do.call("rbind", Map(function(a1, a2, g) {
    xvals <- c(0, sin(seq(a1, a2, len = 30)) * size, 0) + x
    yvals <- c(0, cos(seq(a1, a2, len = 30)) * size, 0) + y
    data.frame(x = xvals, y = yvals, group = g, rownum = rownum)
  }, head(angles, -1), tail(angles, -1), groups))
}

x %>%
  mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(x = 1:3, y = 1) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_map(~ with(.x, make_pie(x, y, sqrt(samplesize)/20, 
                                c("a1", "a2", "a3"),
                                c(a1, a2, a3), r))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = group, group = interaction(group, rownum))) +
  geom_polygon() +
  annotate("text", x = 1:3, y = 1.6, label = c("a", "b", "c"), size = 7) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works for me. The only problem is that I have 18 pie chart and I want to put them in the different rows in the page, but here when I change the mutate(x = 1:8, y = 1) %>%, it puts all the pies in one row. Do you know how can I put 18 pies in 9 rows and three columns? Thank you

Comment: @Sadcow  if you want 3 columns try `x = rep(1:6, 3), y = rep(1:3, each = 6)`